# Firefox ignores CSS comma separated classes

Tags: css

I've a weird issue regarding comma separated css classes. Firefox ignores the following class `.Control-fakeSelect::after`: - [See result](http://henriklagerstam.se/ff_ignore_comma_seperated.jpg)

```
.Control-field::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
.Control-fakeSelect::after{
    background-color: transparent; /* 1 */
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2215%22%20height%3D%229%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2015%209%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22%23444%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M11.773.583L7.38%204.976%202.987.583C2.432.028%201.532.028.977.583c-.555.555-.555%201.455%200%202.01L6.374%207.99c.28.278.642.417%201.006.417.09%200%20.182-.01.27-.026.27-.05.526-.18.734-.39l5.4-5.397c.554-.555.554-1.455%200-2.01-.556-.555-1.456-.555-2.01%200z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: transparent; /* 1 */
    content: "";
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 1; /* 1 */
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 15px;
}
```

However if I remove the `.Control-field::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` from the comma separated list so the css looks like this:

```
.Control-fakeSelect::after{
    background-color: transparent; /* 1 */
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2215%22%20height%3D%229%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2015%209%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22%23444%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M11.773.583L7.38%204.976%202.987.583C2.432.028%201.532.028.977.583c-.555.555-.555%201.455%200%202.01L6.374%207.99c.28.278.642.417%201.006.417.09%200%20.182-.01.27-.026.27-.05.526-.18.734-.39l5.4-5.397c.554-.555.554-1.455%200-2.01-.556-.555-1.456-.555-2.01%200z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: transparent; /* 1 */
    content: "";
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 1; /* 1 */
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 15px;
}
```

Firefox recognizes the css-class. [See result](http://henriklagerstam.se/single_css_class.jpg).

Anyone experienced this issue before or know why Firefox ignores the ::after when added to comma separated css classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is correct and intentional. Your selector is:

```
.Control-field::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
.Control-fakeSelect::after
```

As Firefox cannot (will not) parse the first one, since it's vendor specific, it considers the whole rule atomically invalid, as it doesn't know how to **fully** apply it. IE and Edge will do the same.

So your observation is wrong, it's not related to the `:after` or the comma, it's related to the `-webkit` prefix, and it's intentional and by specs correct behaviour. Split the rule in 2 and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @niels-keurentjes, I didn't know that browser where ignoring it since it's vendor specific. Too bad with duplicate css though :p

Comment: I found out about this the hard way too some years ago, but it's actually well specced behaviour when you dive into it  :)

Comment: Wow!!! I have been tearing down my hair in the past 5 hours! Thanks for saving me from baldness...